# self join in postgresql with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-1.4

Firstly, Django adds unnecessary quotes, this causes PostgreSQL syntax error:

```
Model.objects.extra(tables=['(SELECT ... FROM model) AS "model_alias"'],
                    where=...)
```

produces

```
SELECT ... FROM "model" , "(SELECT ...) AS "model_alias"" WHERE ...
```

-- syntax error, where

```
SELECT ... FROM "model" , (SELECT ...) AS "model_alias" WHERE ...
```

is OK.

Secondly, it ignores extra occurance of table name in `tables` parameter of `extra` method, while [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#extra) promises that alias should be created:

```
Model.objects.extra(tables=['model'], where=...)
```

produces just `SELECT ... FROM "model" WHERE ...` -- without alias.

Where is the mistake?
How to overcome such Django's behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do use raw SQL to do this. See [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). It might look something like this:

```
Model.objects.raw("""
    SELECT * FROM 'model' JOIN 'model_alias' ON (...) 
    WHERE (...)
""")
```

Comment: I consider raw SQL querying as the last case, because it forbids feather specifying and reusing of the query.

Comment: I agree. Django's ORM is unfortunately limited when it comes to joins.  I find myself needing to do raw SQL frequently for more complicated queries. The other option is to do the self-join and computation in Python, but this has performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, have you tried this?

```
Model.objects.extra(tables=["(SELECT ... FROM model) AS 'model_alias'"],
                    where=...)
```

I haven't worked with objects.extra much, but I think this should work. I don't know about the second one, but make sure you've read all the documentation for where/tables.

Answer (score 0):

Extra is a way to attach fields to query sets, and it's not meant for sub queries. You are going to have to make use of [Django's aggregation system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).